# InvalidFormatting exception for replacing %' with %' followed by next line

Tags: java, string, replace

String input="abcpqr % ' ";

Want to do 
input.replace(" ' "," '%n ");

It creates some formatting exception.

Is there a way out if I want to keep using replace and %n?

Comment: You are trying to achieve this using which language?

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 2.7, the command

```
input="abcpqr%'"

print input.replace("'","'%n")
print input.replace("'","'%ABCDE")
```

prints

```
abcpqr%'%n
abcpqr%'%ABCDE
```

Your code is working fine here.

**EDIT**:

Since you want the ***o/p to be abcpqr%' be followed by new line***,
you should insert a `\n` at the end of the line.

```
input = "abcpqr%'"
print input.replace("'","'\n")
print input.replace("'","'\n")
```

So it prints

```
abcpqr%'

abcpqr%'
```

Comment: How do you know it is Python?

Comment: I want the o/p to be abcpqr%' followed by new line.

Comment: Then you should change the `input.replace(" ' "," '%n ");` line to something like ` input.replace(" ' "," '%\n ");`. The new line operator is `\n`, not `%n`